# Customizing a ng-boostrap modal with component as content

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I've been trying to customize a modal with a component passed as content. However, I can't seem to make it work. It just displayed a backdrop and the modal itself is not displaying. Watch this forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csyyp8) code for more detail.

Basically I just need to customize the width of the modal. In the guide, it passed the content template reference as described in this [section](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#options). But in my case, I am not passing a TemplateRef but a Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<ng-template let-modal>` wrapper (and its closing half) from your `NgbdModalContent`'s template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

Comment: Ohh thanks, it worked however, when i added a `centered` options, added width wont apply. might be related to modal-dialog classes. thanks anyway for the headsup

Comment: @lemoncodes apply your css stuff on the modal itself (NgbdModalContent), add `styles` there and play your game.